# Почему нельзя преобразованную строку в количество символов поделить на время?

Tags: python

```
start_time = time.time()
answer = input()
end_time = time.time()
delta: int = int(end_time - start_time)
speed: int = int(answer//delta)
```

Это - часть кода

Comment: замените: `speed: int = int(answer//delta)` --> `speed: int = len(answer)//delta`

Comment: @MaxU А я понял. Это блин это чертово указание типа. Никак не могу к нему привыкнуть)